# Inconsistent PDF URLs returned from SharePoint query web service

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, pdf

I'm searching a SharePoint server through web services.  When the web services return Word/Excel/PowerPoint documents, they contain links to the actual files, e.g. http://server/site/mydoc.doc.  When the web services return PDF documents, they contain links to pages that link to the PDF document, e.g. http://server/site/DispForm.aspx?ID=1 which would contain a link to http://server/site/mydoc.pdf.  I've tried _vti_bin/search.asmx with actions Query and QueryEx with no luck.  What is the best way to get a link to the actual document so my app can download it?

Unfortunately, I'm using a large, shared SharePoint installation, and it's very unlikely that the server configuration can be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You need the PDF [IFilter](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=2611) installed on the server in order for the crawl to recognize PDF files and index them correctly. Here are [some instructions from Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/special/acrobat/configuring_pdf_ifilter_for_ms_sharepoint_2007.pdf) (PDF warning!) as well.

Comment: As I said, it's unlikely that I can get the server configuration changed, since it serves a nation-wide organization, and I'm just an intern.  My current solution is to download the page containing the link and extract the link.  Since the page wasn't intended to be machine-readable, it's a huge hack.

Comment: Well I started out as an intern hacking SharePoint and ended up joining the dev team... can't hurt to ask the question. ;D  It isn't really a major change, you'll just need to follow the correct process.